# Bar notsticking to picture css/html

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem with css.
When my image becomes smaller than the list next to it, the grey bar at the bottom of the picture (.meter) won't stick anymore to the picture. I don't know how to solve this. I think it's the opposite of clear that I need, But I couldn't find it on the internet
here is the jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RnSq7/

```
<img src="http://images7.alphacoders.com/407/407975.jpg" />

<section>
<p>
<ul>
<li>long list</li>    
<ul>
</p>
</section>

<div class="meter"><span style="width: 50%"> </span></div>
```

I hope sombeody can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Though simple, this question is clear well explained and includes a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I was starting to think questions like this didn't exist any more. Especially from low rep users! +1

Comment: @Liam you are right, even if the question had a typo, it is nice to see that OP took the time to make a demo explaining the issue and didn't just dump code into SO expecting everybody to understand! +1 too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the order in your markup :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/RnSq7/1/)**

```
<img src="http://images7.alphacoders.com/407/407975.jpg" />
<div class="meter"><span style="width: 50%"> </span>
</div>
<section>
    <p>
        <ul>
            <li>shalalalala</li>
            <li>shalalalala</li>
            <li>shalalalala</li>
            <li>shalalalala</li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </p>
</section>
```

I didn't mention but you are missing the `/` sign on your closing `ul` tag in your fiddle. I corrected that typo in the demo too.

Comment: Better solution than mine

Comment: hmm thank you didn't expect it was that easy But now i'm having a problem that the list starts at the bottom of my image. Will try to fix that ;)

Comment: I removed the float left from the list and that worked. Thanks alot ;)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to take the div and put it just after the img. But if your div will not house any other element, I would suggest to take it off and use 'border-bottom' property.

Option 1:

```
<img src="" />
<div class="meter"><span style="width: 50%"> </span>
</div>
<section>
    <p>
        <ul>
            <li>shalalalala</li>
            <li>shalalalala</li>
            <li>shalalalala</li>
            <li>shalalalala</li>

        </ul>
    <p>
</section>
```

Options 2:

```
<img src="" class="test"/>
```

and then in stylesheet

```
.test {
     border-bottom: 20px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my div houses something else.

Comment: That is what I was think otherwise the border solition would have been the best here is a demo with it : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/RnSq7/5/